# How to concatenate vertically multiple columns and duplicate values in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is the original data:

| fruit | column_A | column_B | column_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | A | B | N/A |
| orange | C | D | E |

And what I want is:

| fruit | column_combined |
| --- | --- |
| apple | A |
| apple | B |
| orange | C |
| orange | D |
| orange | E |

What I've already done is create a new dataframe and use append to combine into one column

```
df = df['column_A'].append(df['column_B']).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.append(df['column_C']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

That will concatenate vertically, but I have no idea to duplicate the fruit columns into the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished by `melt` in the code below. The rest is just some cleanup.

```
(df.melt(id_vars = ['fruit'], value_name='column_combined')
    .drop(columns = 'variable')
    .dropna()
    .sort_values('fruit')
    .reset_index(drop = True)
)
```

output:

```
    fruit   column_combined
0   apple   A
1   apple   B
2   orange  C
3   orange  D
4   orange  E
```